# Multi-Label Classiﬁcation where each label is a Multi-class problem

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, multi-class, multilabel

**Problem:**
Currently, I have 15 classification models(multi-class + binary). Training and Maintaining 15 models take a huge time and cost. Also, I need to inference 15 models for every input. So I thought I could build one multi-label classification problem instead of having 15 models. Am I right about the approach or can anyone suggest a better approach?

**Issue with multi-label approach:**
Multi-Label classification works by building multiple binary classifiers for each class. So If I have 20 labels, the model will build 20 binary classifiers

*Example:*
cat(yes/no)
sunny(yes/no)
windy(yes/no)
Output:
cat, windy


But how can I train Multi-Label Classiﬁcation where each label is a Multi-class or binary-class problem?

*Expected output:* 
label1 - pug (multi-class: pug, dalmatian, husky, german_shepherd)
label2 - sunny(multi-class: sunny, rainy, winter)
label3 - not a tree(binary: tree)

**Hack(but will not work):** 
Melt down the multi-class, so now I will have 8 labels:
[pug, dalmatian, husky, german_shepherd, sunny, rainy, winter, tree]

But the problem with this approach is, I could also get dalmatian as well as husky. Similarly, I could get both sunny and rainy with this approach. 
I need to results to be **mutually non-exclusive** for each label.

Answer (score 2):

There's three common options for this:

- Train 3 separate models. Easy and straightforward to do, but does not exploit potential information across the different targets (which could help neural networks find good internal representations of the data).
- Train a single model that separately outputs multiple targets, which have different loss functions. I.e. one output is label1, another label2 and another label3, which might be trained e.g. using categorical-cross-entropy, categorical-cross-entropy and binary-log-loss, respectively. This is usually easiest done using neural networks and any packages (like PyTorch/`torch`, `fastai`, `keras` etc.) accommodate this out-of-the-box, you just need to look it up in the documentation. That's occasionally hard, because people don't talk about this in a consistent manner, but keywords like "multi-target" should help (multi-label is sometimes also used, but is also used sometimes for having one categorical variable with multiple levels). Models other than neural networks need a lot of manual tinkering to make this work, so would not be my first try.
- Treat all combinations of the levels as your target ("pug-sunny-not-a-tree", "pug-rainy-tree", "husky-snowy-not-a-tree" etc.). Then, you can just train any model to predict these combined categories and break the output apart thereafter. The downside is that you get a lot of categories, so unless you have a lot of data this may be quite inefficient (and some categories not occurring in the training data may be a problem).

Comment: Reg. the first solution, Train 3 separate models: what you're telling is multi-class classification right, not a multi-label classification

Comment: It's one multi-class model for dog type, one multi-class model for weather condition and one binary model for tree/no tree, yes. Taken together they predict all 3 targets. Neural networks are the main class of model (besides special situations where you can e.g. create detailed models of the data generating mechanism for example for some biological system) that in generic situations deal quite well with outputting multiple different things (in contrast things like random forest, gradient boosted trees, traditional statistical regression models deal most easily with just one target).

Comment: Yes, this is my current approach. I need help in merging these 3 models into 1 model something similar like multi-label classification

Comment: For clarification: Firstly, why? Is the hope that this will somehow improve performance? Or is this images (or something else that takes a lot of time with a neural network) and the idea is that this saves time in terms of how fast it runs? Or is it about having a single function people call (even if in the background it's okay if there's multiple models)? Secondly, what is the problem exactly? Is it problems finding in the documentation for how to do it or is it about how this ML-/statistics-wise works (I aimed to answer at a high level above)?

Comment: ok. Currently, I have 15 classification models(multi-class + binary). Training and Maintaining 15 models take a huge time and cost. Also, I need to inference 15 models for every input. So I thought I could build one multi-label classification problem instead of having 15 models. Am I right about the approach or can you suggest a better approach

Comment: 15 models is a plausible approach & if there's a problem with one of them, you can intervene in a targeted manner. I would consider a single model, if deep learning (neutral networks) is a sensible option for the problems you are solving  That's most obvious if your models are already neural networks. Otherwise, is the interpretability/explainability good enough? Need for uncertainty in predictions? Can a NN work good enough for the problem (reasonably likely, of there's a lot of training data, no strong prior information to encode, text/image/audio input, while less clear for tabular data)?